# Shared with me documents in OneDrive for Business disappear after 24 hours

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I have SharePoint 2016 onPrem.  Users can share documents in their OneDrive for Business and they appear in the "Shared with me" area, but they disappear after about 24hrs.

What could be causing this?  Can they stick for a longer time?

Bismarck

Comment: Can you provide more details. Do they not appear at all after 24 hours or do they reappear again?

Comment: When a user shares a document from their OneDrive for Business (on-Prem), it appears almost immediately in the recipients "Shared with me" area of their OneDrive for Business.  However after about 24 hours, it disappears forcing the first user to un-share and re-share again.

Comment: Can you please check how search is been setup and how often full crawl is being run.

Comment: I have to crawls running continuously. 1. Local SharePoint Sites and 2. MySites.

Comment: The MySites Content Source Crawl is set as: sps3s://mysite.company.net